# Link Youtube Channel In Wordpress Site

Tags: wordpress, youtube

I am trying to develop a site where people can find and view videos of my activities from my youtube channel. I am quite new to wordpress but I decided to use it to achieve this purpose.

I have been looking for a wordpress plugin to use to display all the videos from my youtube channel but I have not found any. I used these plugins `Youtube Channel Gallery` and `YouTube Upload Widget`, but none of them work the way I want, they are only able to import one video at a time only when you input the video url. But what I want is to for my video library on my site to update as the videos in my youtube channel updates.

I would appreciate all answers thanks.

Comment: As faar as I know this plugin `Youtube Channel Gallery` has the options you are asking for .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not sure how to configure this plugin `Youtube Channel Gallery` . See the link below :

http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-show-latest-videos-from-youtube-channel-in-wordpress/